# Python: handle sys.exit() in doctests

Tags: python, doctest, systemexit

I am trying to use python doctests to test an error message that is being printed in a function. Below is my code

```
import sys
def get_values(vals=[]):
    """
    Should split key:val and give values
    >>> get_values(["abc"])
    Error: could not get the values
    """
    values = []
    for val in vals:
        try:
            kv = val.split(':')
            k = kv[0]
            v = kv[1]
            values.append(v)
        except Exception:
            print_msg("Error: could not get the values")
    return values

def print_msg(msg):
    print msg
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    import doctest
    try:
        doctest.testmod()
    except doctest.DocTestFailure, failure:
        print 'DocTestFailure:'
        sys.exit(1)
    print "doctests complete"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the doctest, I am getting the below:

```
**********************************************************************
File "abc.py", line 7, in __main__.get_values
Failed example:
    get_values(["abc"])
Exception raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/depot/python/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1254, in __run
    compileflags, 1) in test.globs
  File "<doctest __main__.get_values[0]>", line 1, in <module>
    get_values(["abc"])
  File "abc.py", line 18, in get_values
    print_msg("Error: could not get the values")
  File "abc.py", line 23, in print_msg
    sys.exit(1)
  SystemExit: 1
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
1 of   1 in __main__.get_values
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
doctests complete
```

Can anyone help me how to handle the sys.exit(1) while running the doctests?

Comment: Instead of `sys.exit`, you can do `raise KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library to [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) `sys.exit`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this without using external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

As I looked for, doctest has nothing for that.
I use this pattern to catch SystemExit (and other Exceptions too) together with stdout messages:

```
    >>> def function_with_exception():
    ...     print >>sys.stdout, 'something into stdout'
    ...     print >>sys.stderr, 'something into stderr'
    ...     sys.exit(1)
    ...     # raise Exception('xxx')
    >>> def test_function_with_exception(**kwargs):
    ...     try:
    ...         function_with_exception(**kwargs)
    ...     except BaseException as e:
    ...         print '{0.__class__.__name__}({0})'.format(e)
    >>> test_function_with_exception()
    something into stdout
    SystemExit(1)
```